# ASP.NET - How do I 'follow' a redirect from a response to an http post generated by a server side process?

Tags: asp.net

I have a scenario that I'm not sure how to handle in ASP.NET.

I am setting up an automated payment system that is a conversion from the previous manual, user driven payment system.

The system previously worked like so:

1.The user fills in a payment form, and submits the form.

2.This causes an http post to a remote page.

3.The remote page processes the post data, and the payment.

4.The remote page forwards the web browser on to a call back page on the original website, along with query string data which allows the recording of the response.

The automated system checks for due payments, and then works like so:

1.Create a server side http post and submit.

2.....

And here is where I've got to. I've got an HttpWebRequest, and I then get the HttpWebResponse which I can read.

The problem is that the request doesn't seem to follow the response. I don't see evidence of the code in the Callback page firing.

Is as though the redirect in the remote page isn't honoured unless a browser is used to do the posting.

Hope this makes sense?

Any pointers on how I should be handling this type of scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you set the [AllowAutoRedirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.allowautoredirect.aspx) property to `true`?